# Redirect loop error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have hide .php extension of all the pages using .htaccess

But when some one types link address with .php extension the page still opens up with .php extension. I have tried permanent redirect .php page to non php page for example example.com/about.php to example.com/about but its giving me redirect loop error.

Here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)/([\d\w-\s]*)/([\d\w-\s]*)/([\d\w-\s]*)/?$ product_detail.php?id=$1&category=$3&parent_category=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Options +MultiViews




ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: what part of your rewrite rule is for "rewriting things ending in .php"? Because it's extremely specific, and has no "php" before that `$`

Comment: I have used "Options +MultiViews" Is there any other way of hiding .php extension and redirect .php with non-php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your code like this in root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)/([\d\w\s-]*)/([\d\w\s-]*)/([\d\w\s-]*)/?$ product_detail.php?id=$1&category=$3&parent_category=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Can you help me redirect [link](http://www.example.com/index) to [link](http://www.example.com/)

Comment: Glad it worked. May I know how you have a link of `http://www.example.com/index` since my first rule will redirect `http://www.example.com/index.php` to `http://www.example.com/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to the top of your rules (just under `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```